# Transition doesn´t work when assigned in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I have the problem that when i assign a margin property in my JavaScript on an element, there are no transition effects. I already looked for similar questions and already tried it with an event listener. I also tried it with setTimeout and it worked but not i want it to work. It shall be a smooth transition , where the image which floats in is above the current and floats in from the side where you pressed the button.

In my editor the code works but without transitions.

```js
var counter = 0;
var slides = [];
function scrollThrough(n) {
  alert("sd");
    slides = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
    if(counter + n < 0){
        counter = slides.length-1;
        slides[counter].style.transition = "none";
        slides[counter].style.marginLeft="100%";
        for(i = 0 ; i< slides.length ;i++){
            slides[i].style.zIndex = i;
        }
        slides[counter].style.transition = "all 0.5s linear";
        slides[counter].style.marginLeft ="0";
    }
    else if(counter + n > slides.length-1){
        counter = 0;
        slides[counter].style.transition = "none";
        slides[counter].style.marginLeft="-100%";
        for(i = 0 ; i< slides.length ;i++){
            slides[i].style.zIndex = slides.length-i;
        }
        slides[counter].style.transition = "all 0.5s linear";
        slides[counter].style.marginLeft ="0";
    }
    else{
        counter += n;
        slides[counter].style.transition = "none";
        slides[counter].style.marginLeft= (-n)*100+"%";
        slides[counter].style.zIndex = slides.length;
        slides[counter-n].style.zIndex = slides.length-1;
        for(i = 0 ; i< slides.length-2 ;i++){
            if(i == counter || i == counter-n){
            }
            else{
               slides[i].style.zIndex = i;
            }
        }
        slides[counter].style.transition = "all 0.5s linear";
        slides[counter].style.marginLeft ="0";
    }
}
```

```css
#newsline{
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;

}

.img{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    transition:all 0.5s linear;
}

#newsline a img{
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%; 
}

.move{
    z-index: 3;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: table;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255,0.25) ;
}


.move:hover{
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255,0.6);
}

.move p{
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    color: rgb(250, 255, 255,0.7);
    font-size: 250%;
    background-color: none;
}

.move p:hover{
    color: darkslategrey;
}


.next{
    right: 6%;
}

.previous{
    left: 6%;
}

.one{
    z-index: 2;
}

.two{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="newsline" >
            <div class="move next" onclick="scrollThrough(1)"><p>⮚</p></div>
            <div class="move previous" onclick="scrollThrough(-1)"><p>⮘</p></div>
            <a href="" class="img one"><img     src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/8ccb4ec4225b290726ae9be975220ff4.jpg"></a>
            <a href="" class="img two"><img src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/4362856-bleach-wallpaper-hd.jpg"></a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please don't post links to your code. Post it right here in your question as a "code snippet".

Comment: Maybe you can try adding a new class (like counter1), write all the required styles for it in the css and then use element.classList.add() and element.classList.remove() to change the style of your element in js.

Comment: Even with the `transition-property` set to `all`, the property that you want transitioned must have a default value set for it in the CSS.

Comment: Yeah i will try that later @Andriy Dmytruk

Comment: @Scott Marcus isn&#39;t it enough when i Set The value of margin right before it should be moved to the &quot;dafault&quot; value of 100% in Javascript. When i do the Same manually in CSS, the Transition can be seen.

Comment: No. The property that will be transitioned must have an initial value set in CSS. This is exactly why you see the transition when you do it manually and you don't when you set the initial value in JavaScript.

Comment: I did it like @Andriy Dmytruk suggested and it worked.There was also a timeout needed. Thank you!